# What is the value of $\sum_{n \geq 1} \epsilon^n/n$, where $\epsilon$ is a $k^\text{th}$ root of $1$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, analytic-number-theory

I wonder what is the value of
$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\epsilon^n}{n}$$
where $\epsilon$ is a $k^\text{th}$ root of $1$, say $\epsilon=e^{(2\pi i l)/k}$ for a fixed $l=1,\ldots,k-1$.

My idea is that the sum is one of the values of
$$-\log(1-\epsilon)=-\log(re^{i \phi})=-\log r -i \phi-2\pi i \mathbb Z,$$
but which one?

Comment: Depends quite heavily on $k$ and $l$. If $k=1$, the series famously diverges...

Comment: If $\epsilon$ is a k-th root of 1, doesn't $\epsilon ^k$ equal 1?

Comment: The series $\sum z^n/n$ has its value given by the principal branch of the logarithm.

Comment: @Wojowu, what does it means (here, $\epsilon$ is on the boundary of the region where $\log(1-x)$ converges)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find in the literature of Complex Analysis, that

$\enspace\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{i2\pi x n}}{n}=i\pi(\frac{1}{2}-x)-\ln(2\sin(\pi x))\enspace$ for $\enspace 0<x<1$ .

To answer your question set $\displaystyle x:=\frac{l}{k}$ with $k\geq 2$.

Note:

$i2\pi \mathbb{Z}$ disappears because the main branch of the logarithm has to be used. E.g set $x=\frac{1}{2}$ then you know why.